# Streamsets DC and Crate exception. ERROR: SQLParseException: line 1:13: no viable alternative at input 'CHARACTERISTICS'

Tags: crate, streamsets

I am trying to connect to Crate as a Streamsets Data collector pipeline origin ( JDBC Consumer ). However I get this error: "JDBC_00 - Cannot connect to specified database: com.streamsets.pipeline.api.StageException: JDBC_06 - Failed to initialize connection pool: com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolInitializationException: Exception during pool initialization: ERROR: SQLParseException: line 1:13: no viable alternative at input 'CHARACTERISTICS' "
Why am I getting this error ? The Crate JDBC Driver version is 2.1.5 and Streamsets Data collector version is 2.4.0.0.

Comment: Could you post the full stack trace to the StreamSets sdc-user Google Group? See https://streamsets.com/community for details. You could also try the Crate Google Group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/crateio

Comment: I have done so.

Comment: Problem solved. Within Streamsets DC I had to uncheck Enforce Read-only Connection on the Advanced tab of my JDBC query consumer configuration.

Comment: Great! You should add this as the answer to the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@gashey already solved the issue. Within Streamsets DC uncheck **Enforce Read-only Connection** on the **Advanced tab** of my JDBC query consumer configuration
(see https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/crateio/hBexxel2KQw/kU34mrsJBgAJ).

We will update the streamsets-documentation with the workaround. https://crate.io/docs/tools/streamsets/